# Is there a way to insert `conditional logic` into Photoshop's Batch Automation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I am currently trying to optimize a folder full of images for the web, using Photoshop.  Given the volume of images, I am opting to use the **Automate > Batch** method.

As well as changing the image quality and file format, I would like to reduce all images over 2500px by 2500px to 900px by 900px.  Unfortunately, there are some images, in the same folder, which are below 900px by 900px.  Of which, I do not want their image sizes to be altered.

As such, is there a way to implement some kind of condition logic that allows the **Automate > Batch** feature to reduce all images over 2500px by 2500px to 900px by 900px whilst ignoring all images below 900px by 900px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an action from **Menu Image** > **Automate** > **Fit Image...**

And checking **Don't Enlarge**

[image]

All images below 900px by 900px will be ignored.

Then play a **Batch** using this reducing size action.

Comment: how do you play a batch with fit image?